# iPhone 4 requires recalibrating the compass almost every time I use it

Tags: iphone, compass

My iPhone 4 asks me to recalibrate the compass by using a figure 8 motion almost every time I use it.

I'm wondering if this happens because my phone is defective, or if other people are having the same issue.

Comment: I have the same problems. My iPhone behaves like this since the first day.

Answer (score 6):

According to an [Apple support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2767):

> After updating or restoring your device, you may notice that the recalibration alert appears more frequently. This is expected behavior, because the calibration database is being recreated. The frequency diminishes over time as you calibrate the device for various locations.

Comment: I experience the same symptoms as Senseful, but have never updated or restored my device. The linked Apple support article explains the need for recalibration, but the quoted paragraph is IMHO not the answer; it just says that the problem may be worse than it already is after an update or restore.

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"We're sorry. We can't find the article you're looking for."*

Comment: @Pang Seems like Apple has removed documentation for a product discontinued over four years ago. Probably newer hardware has different sensor(s) as well as different operating logic. Here are links to [the referred page at the time of the answer](https://web.archive.org/web/20100830050833/http://support.apple.com:80/kb/TS2767) and to [the last version online](https://web.archive.org/web/20140227004932/http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2767).